# I baked sourdough bread in metal loaf pan lined with parchment paper. The bread came out with black from the pan on the bread, can we eat it?

Tags: food-safety

I baked sourdough bread in a metal loaf pan lined with parchment paper. The bread came out with black from the pan on the bread, can we eat it?

Comment: If you used parchment paper, how did anything from the pan get onto the bread? Are you sure it's not just a burnt/dark part? What kind of pan- nonstick, plain aluminum, something else?

Comment: Did the parchment burn into char? If not your question is based on a thing that could not have happened, and if so, it's burnt parchment. Or as @Esther suggests, plain old burnt crust.